# Can't pass data in view (laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to pass an array from controller in view but it doesn't show error because it rezognise the variable but the data are not there, meanwhile when i try dd() in controller, i have data there.
Below is my code:

//Controller

```
public function showMessage(){
    $id = Input::get('recordid');

    foreach ($id as $chat_id) {
        $history = Chat::where('chat_id','=', $chat_id)->get();  

        return View::make('chat.chatview', compact($history));
    } 
}
```

//View

```
@extends ('master')
@section ('content')

<div class="container">
    <h1 style="color: white;">Chat History</h1>
    <?php if (isset($history)) { ?>
           @foreach($history as $row)
           <table>
               <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $history ;?></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
           @endforeach
    <?php } ?>
</div>
@stop
```

//route

```
Route::get('chathistory', function(){
    return View::make('chat/chatview');});
```

The array that I get is from another view with the code below:
//view

```
@foreach($chat as $row)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $row->chat_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->fullname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->transcript_text }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $row->duration }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="History" class="btn pull-left" name="status[]" id="status[]" onclick="javascript:changeStatus('{{$row->chat_id}}','{{$arr}}')"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        <input name="recordid[]" id="recordid[]" type="hidden">
                        <?php $arr++; ?>
                        @endforeach
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function changeStatus(id, arr){
                                        $('[id^=recordid]').eq(arr).val(id);
                                    }
                        </script>
```

//Route

```
Route::get('individual', function(){
    $chat = Chat::all();
    return View::make('chat/individual')->with('chat', $chat);});

Route::post('individual','HomeController@showMessage');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
return View::make('chat.chatview', compact($history));
```

to

```
return View::make('chat.chatview', ['history' => $history]);
```

or

```
return View::make('chat.chatview')->with(compact('history'));
```

and try again.

Comment: That worked but now I am only getting the data from the first row. When I press the status button, it only works for the first row, and when I try for any other rows it doesnt return anything

Answer (score 0):

Change here

```
return View::make('chat.chatview')->with('history',$history);
```